# How to use allure_commons for custom framework in Python

Tags: python, allure

I am trying to integrate my python tests with allure for reporting. I prefer to use `allure python commons` instead of `allure-pytest` due to my framework restriction but I couldn’t find any documentation related to `allure python commons`. I have captured the test result and wanted to pass that data to allure to generate the allure json files which then can be processed for allure report generation using `allure serve` command. How can i achieve this? Any suggestions would be very much helpful. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

If you succeeded with the generation of results files, then here is the way to generate the report: https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_report_generation